# chosen data-placeholder doesn't display fully for listboxes

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-chosen

I have an asp.net listbox and I'm using the [jquery chosen plugin](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/).
The data-placeholder value doesn't seem to always work with list boxes.
For instance see the image:

[image]

Notice the list box for `Region` it says "Select Re" then it stops...its quite random look at the list box for city that works fine.  But look at the list box for country it is supposed to say `Select Country...` but it shows `Select Country..` (missing the last period).  My listbox control's asp.net markup is as such:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="lbRegion" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" class="chosen-select"
             data-placeholder="Select Region..." SelectionMode="Multiple"
             OnSelectedIndexChanged="lbRegion_OnSelectedIndexChanged" ToolTip="Select Region...">
</asp:ListBox>
```

I've tried re-creating it, etc...but to no avail.  What gives?

Here's my jquery that includes the class for chosen:

```
$(".chosen-select").chosen({
            search_contains: true,
            no_results_text: "Oops, nothing found!",
            allow_single_deselect: true
        });
        $('.chosen-container').css('width', '200px');
```

Comment: just curious, why is the region select mode multiple?

Comment: Because it's a multi select list box (more than 1 value).

Comment: Could you link to a fiddle or a live page with this issue?

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/B4X8k/; can you provide more context? Is opened in a popup? In what browser are you facing the issue? Are you using the latest chosen (1.0)?

Comment: I am also facing the same problem...But once I click on it, the placeholder value is shown normally.

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward I know asp.net translates into normal markup however there may be some differences  between my code and yours.  Can you try it on asp.net listboxes as I have shown in my example, try a few of them and report back if you experience the same issue?

Comment: @SantoshGhimire - We also face the same issue, clicking on the listbox and clicking away from it fixes the issue, however this is not ideal.  Also Irvin Dominin aka Edward - I wonder if it makes a difference but these "listboxes" are within an asp.net update panel...Can you try that?

Comment: Isn't this just a CSS issue?

Comment: @Phearst - how so?  The width of the container is larger then the text being placed in the data placeholder.

Comment: @JonH Take a look at this issue https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/1162

Comment: I've just experienced something like this before. Show me some more code and then maybe I'll be able can fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed that each listbox on the page was given the class `default`.  I am not saying this is a definite answer but it is a workaround.  Simply add this to your jquery:

`$(".default").css("width", "175px");`

Use the width to your liking, in this case I used 175px.

Comment: You may want to narrow down the selector - `.chosen-choices .search-field .default` so that way you  don't accidentally change anything else on the page, as `.default` is pretty generic.

Answer (score 10):

Issue about `Select Country..` reproduced here: http://jsfiddle.net/D3FUc/, I'll search deeply the reason why of the issue.

The only woraround I found is to override the specific container class like:

```
li.search-field {
    width: 100%;
}
li.search-field input.default {
    width: auto !important;
}
```

Issue: https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/1162#issuecomment-30229366

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/D3FUc/1/

Comment: Hi Irvin, the other thing I noticed is all list boxes seem to get a class of `default` so this can be easily resolved with jquery using a css property.  `$(".default").css("width", "175px");`

Comment: @JonH Yes, it's the second solution in the css code pasted li.search-field input.default; I think it's better using pure css (no overhead and always applied by default), and will be better trying to use a more strict selector, because the chosen .default it's a bit sad as class name

Comment: This was the answer for me, although I changed `width: auto !important;` to `width: 100% !important`

Answer (score 1):

Setting the width explicitly in the initialization options seems to fix the problem on [Irvin's example](http://jsfiddle.net/D3FUc/) :

```
$('.chosen-select').chosen({ width: '200px' });
```

- [**documentation**](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/#custom-width-support)
- [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/D3FUc/2/) (works with FF 26.0)

---

> we had done this but using a css style. –  JonH

I know.

Somehow, `chosen` computes a length for the placeholder label, and assigns it in the label's markup, in the `style` attribute.
I can't tell at what point in the internal rendering this length is computed, but from what the test shows :

- if you only have a css rule, the length is incorrect for the first display,
- if you pass the width as an explicit option, on the other hand, the length is correct.

My blind guess is : the select placeholder's width is read at a point where it has not yet reached its final value - maybe before it was inserted at its final place in the DOM, and hence before the css rule applies.

Comment: Just on this, I found it didn't work for percentage width values. e.g. `$('.chosen-select').chosen({ width: '95%' });` produced the same truncation problem.

Answer (score 0):

The css solution changes the appearance of the select box so I didn't want to use it. I managed to work around by calling the following after the chosen is displayed.

```
//to fix placeholder in chosen
$('select').trigger('chosen:updated')
```